# Moving image with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am new to pygame. I was just trying to move an image with pygame but it fails my code is

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
img = pygame.image.load('tank.jpg')

white = (255, 64, 64)

w = 640
h = 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

screen.fill((white))

running = 1

while running:

  x = 5
  x++
  y  = 10
  y++

  screen.fill((white))
  screen.blit(img,(x,y))
  pygame.display.flip()
  pygame.update()
```

I have tried this code to move the image. But it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

1)your overwriting `x` and `y` in every iteration of while loop

2) you can't do `x++` in python, use `x+=1` instead

3) `pygame.update()` --> I think you meant `pygame.display.update()`

Try using this:

```
running = 1                     
x= 5                            
y = 5                           
while running:                  
    x +=1                       
    y +=1                       
    screen.fill((white))        
    screen.blit(img,(x,y))      
    pygame.display.flip()       
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @user3830347 you don't have to use `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.display.update()` together - they do (almost) the same.

Comment: user3830347 is this what you've expected? Please let me know if it works.

Comment: `user3830347` left SO 23 minutes ago.

Comment: @furas pygame.display.flip() and pygame.display.update() does the exact same thing, when nothing is passed as parameters into update.